# How can we move Dynamic file from one folder to another in Unix server through Java code

Tags: java, unix

I want to fetch file name value from Text Box and move the file in unix server from one folder to another folder.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
         {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println();
           FileName = TxtFileName.getText().trim();
           String command="mv '$FileName' /bgw/feeds/ibs/request/ready";
           if(ae.getSource().equals(Process))
            {
                System.out.println("Working properly");

                    switch (name) 
                    {
                        case "IBS":
                                System.out.println("Inside IBS");

                        try
                        {                       
                            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
                            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                            JSch jsch = new JSch();
                            Session session=jsch.getSession(SSHCommandExecutor.user,"bbgw2-2.mt.att.com",22);
                            session.setPassword(SSHCommandExecutor.passwd);
                            session.setConfig(config);
                            session.connect();
                            System.out.println("Connected");
                            Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
                            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
                            channel.setInputStream(null);
                            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
                            InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
                            channel.connect();
                            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
                            while(true)
                            {
                                while(in.available()>0)
                                {
                                    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                                    if(i<0)break;
                                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                                }
                                if(channel.isClosed())
                                {
                                    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                                    break;
                                }
                                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(InterruptedException ee){}
                            }
                            channel.disconnect();
                            session.disconnect();
                            System.out.println("DONE");
                            setVisible(true);                       
                        }
                        catch(JSchException | IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    break;
```

I am trying to move the file taken from Text Box from one folder in unix server to another folder. Please help me out.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I am not able to move the file which I am getting from the text box...

Comment: what is the error/exception ?

Comment: The code is executing but the file is not moving.. Its not throwing any exception also

Comment: can you debug and see if it gets executed

Comment: I tried a lot ... But no luck... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55339/discussion-between-priya89-and-jigar-joshi).